# Insert .CSV into AspNetUsers using .NET Core MVC 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

So basically I'm trying obtain the uploaded .csv file from the client side and insert it into Dbo.AspNetUsers.
I've defined the below file for the three fields I obtain from the .csv

```
public class CsvStudent : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Course { get; set; }
    }
```

And here's the code to upload the .csv from the client side.

```
<form class="col-xs-12" method="post" asp-controller="User" asp-action="ImportUsers" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's the controller which should obtain the uploaded .csv so far.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ImportUsers(IFormFile file)
        {
            var data = new MemoryStream();
            file.CopyTo(data);
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
            var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
            var records = csvReader.GetRecords<User>();
```

I'm not even sure if the code above is correctly reading the .csv, but basically what I'd like to do here, as I've explained in the first paragraph,
is to upload the records to the dbo.AspNetUsers table and I'm unsure about how to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to the below demo:

1.Model and ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class CsvStudent : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CsvStudent>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

}
```

2.CSV file :

```
Name,Number,Course,Password
Sherry,6,Chinese,Sherry123#
Daniel,2,Math,Daniel456#
```

3.Controller :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ImportUsers(IFormFile file)
    {
        var data = new MemoryStream();
        await file.CopyToAsync(data);
        data.Position = 0;
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
        var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader ,new CsvHelper.Configuration.Configuration
        {
            HasHeaderRecord = true, //Gets or sets a value indicating if the CSV file has a header record. Default is true.
            HeaderValidated = null,//Gets or sets the function that is called when a header validation check is ran
            MissingFieldFound=null //Gets or sets the function that is called when a missing field is found.
        });
        var records = csvReader.GetRecords<CsvStudent>().ToList();
        foreach (var item in records)
        {
           //check if the user has been existing in db 
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(item.Name);

            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new CsvStudent
                {
                    Name = item.Name,
                    Number = item.Number,
                    Course = item.Course,
                    UserName = item.Name
                };
                await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, item.Password);
            }
        }
         return Json(records);
    }
```

More details on CsvHelper.Configuration , you could refer to [here](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/Configuration/) .

Comment: That's more or less what I needed, I'mma mark it as correct!